# Exception Handling C# - how to accept only numbers 1-5, no strings

Tags: c#

So I’m kind of confused about how to do exception handling. I have this menu I created that has 5 options, so the user enters a number 1-5. I need to make an exception handler for when the user enters a string or number greater than 5. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: what control do you use to enter numbers?

Comment: I think you might want to look into using input validation. Is this for windows forms, WPF, a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use an `Exception` to handle the flow of your code unless you wish to stop abruptly the current flow and communicate to an upper layer of your code of an 'exceptional' situation that need to be addressed by the calling code.

In your case a simple [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) will solve your problem.
Supposing that your app is a console application you could code something like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DisplayMenu();
    while(true)
    {
        int menuChoice;
        string userInput = Console.Readline();
        if(Int32.TryParse(userInput, out menuChoice))
        {
            if(menuChoice >= 1 && menuChoice <= 5)
               RunCommand(menuChoice);
            else
               Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1-5");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("A number between 1-5 is required!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the type of thing that you should be using exceptions for.  Just use an if-statement, and the tell the user to try again

```
int num;
if(int.TryParse(userInput, out num) == false || num> 5 || num< 1)
{
    ShowError("don't do that");
}
```

Comment: Provide a check `if(!int.TryParse(...))` and you've got the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use exception handling to do this.  This sounds more like a validation thing.  Take a look at the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) if this is for web.  If you really want to throw an exception then you could do something like this:

```
if(myValue < 1 || myValue > 5)
{
   Throw new System.Exception("Out of range!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is having a while loop until the user inputs the right values.

Just a quick example. This is assuming the menu you're talking about is a Console menu.

```
    int userInput = -1;
    while (true){
      Console.WriteLine("Input value:");
      try{
        userInput = Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (userInput <1 || userInput >5){
          throw new Exception();
        }
      }
      catch{
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        continue;
      }
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to, you can use a regular expression to verify input.  I wouldn't throw an exception though as this isn't really the purpose of exception handling

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:
Regex Class (System.Text.RegularExpressions)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[1-5]*$");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
   //true
}
else
 MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
```